# R delete all col with NA except one col

Tags: r

I have `X` to `X.61` col. in data table `Df`. I want R to delete all columns with `NA`.
I have used the code below which works great.

```
Df <-  Df[, which(unlist(lapply(Df, function(x)!all(is.na(x))))),with=F]
```

Now, I want the same thing but want to retain column `X.52` even if all values are `NA`. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will keep the selected column(s) even if all their values are `NA`.

I will make up a data.frame and instead of `X.52` select column name `V3`. All you have to do is to adapt the code.

```
Df <- matrix(1:24, nrow = 4)
Df[, 2:4] <- NA
Df <- as.data.frame(Df)

inx1 <- which(names(Df) %in% "V3")
inx2 <- which(sapply(Df, function(x) !all(is.na(x))))
Df <- Df[, sort(c(inx1, inx2))]

Df
#  V1 V3 V5 V6
#1  1 NA 17 21
#2  2 NA 18 22
#3  3 NA 19 23
#4  4 NA 20 24
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to Say without example but try this:

```
 ids = apply(Df,2,function(x){print(x);return (NA %in% x);});
`Df[,-setdiff(ids,52)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add that as another condition in `which` function using "&":

```
Df <-  Df[, which(unlist(lapply(Df, function(x)!all(is.na(x))))&colnames(Df)!="X.52"),with=F]
```